# How can I make a quick edit text link to auto fill form information from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

How can I make a quick edit text link to auto fill form information from a mysql database? So basically, you click on the number and it fills in the create/edit transaction with the information from the database. Ignore the create/editagent/client. The record.No will be a field not auto assign b/c it will be replacing the current info.

[image]

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"agentclient");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"propertydescription");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"transactiontype");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"applicabledocument"); 
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"received");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"paid");

?>
```

Comment: You will need to send an AJAX call with the id of the transaction.

The AJAX should echo the data you want (XML is best format IMHO) which you then parse with Javascript and insert into the fields.

If you provide some code, a more comprehensive answer may occur...

Comment: Added the php from the table

Answer (score 0):

Use a string to hold selected number,use the stored value in the string to search for the required row.Use another string to pull the information from the database and use # to split the columns.Save each column to a specific string which you will assign to where the value should be auto filled.

Answer (score 0):

Why get those fields from mysql? You can set default values for your user input in html with value option.

Ex: `<input type="text" name="fname" value="John">`

Comment: They come from the database.